# How can custom fonts be added in React Native without using "link"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I've been trying to add a custom .ttf font in my React Native project but Metro keeps telling me it's an "Unrecognized font family" in the iOS simulator. At first I tried using `npx react-native link`, but I found out this was deleted and that I would have to add them manually.

I then followed an article where I created a Font group in Xcode, added the font files there, updated my `Info.plist` file with the fonts to use, and tried restarting my React Native build. This also didn't work.

How are custom fonts supposed to be added in React Native now that linking is no longer an option?

Answer (score 0):

This library will be helpful to you. I am also using it myself. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset.

Comment: I tried using this and it looks like it linked them, but I can't see it in the app. The "Unrecognized font" error went away, but the font is not being applied. Any idea why?

Comment: The font family name must be exact for iOS support, sometimes the font name can cause the error. example:- Roboto-Regular.ttf (This name font is supported in ios but not this RobotoRegular.ttf)

Comment: For some reason this isn't working either. My font family names are exactly as they appear in the filename without the extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution.** After hours of not knowing what was wrong, I finally figured out that you have specify a platform, such as `npx react-native run-ios`.

I had previously been running `npx react-native start` which caused an error, most likely having to do with React compiling the project to both Android and iOS (I've only set up iOS fonts so far).

`npx react-native-asset` helped to set up my `info.plist` file automatically and created an Xcode group for fonts.